# Synonym für bittersüss gesucht

Tags: synonym, latin

Ich suche schon seit längerem das vom Lateinischen abstammende Synonym für `bittersüss`.

Als erklärendes Beispiel:

> schwermütig - melancholisch

Die Suche im Internet wird durch die vielen Treffer für Schokolade und den Bittersüssen Nachtschatten nicht leichter.

Kann mir jemand weiterhelfen?

**Edit 20190427-01:59**
Zur Verdeutlichung, ich suche ein Synonym/Fremdwort für ein bittersüsses Gefühl wie es zum Beispiel durch das Lied "Bitter Sweet Symphony" von "The Verve" zum Ausdruck gebracht wird.

Für Schokolade und dergleichen ist bittersüss oder meinetwegen auch zartbitter völlig ausreichend.

**Edit 20190705-22:31**
Ich habe die Antwort von Rudy Velthuis ausgewählt da sie am deutlichsten aufzeigt das meine Frage keine Antwort zu haben scheint.

Comment: Bei Schokolade ist es zartbitter.

Comment: Vielleicht kann Marzipanherz erhellendes zur Diskussion beitragen?

Comment: Muss es Latein sein? Eingedeutschtes Latein?

Comment: Und was ist verkehrt an "Bittersüß"? Sprich, in wiefern wäre eine eins-zu-eins Übersetzung nicht auch unzureichend?

Comment: @vectory  Ich nehme an, Griechisch wird auch gehen. Ich denke, Kitana meint mit "Lateinisch" eigentlich: "aus den alten europäischen Bildungssprachen stammend".

Comment: _Melancholisch_ stammt nicht vom Lateinischen, sondern vom Altgriechischen _cholé_ (die Galle) ab.

Comment: @userunknown Marzipanherz hat sich vor ca. 6 Monaten gelöscht (oder ist gelöscht worden)

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf: Wie bedauerlich!

Comment: @userunknown leider bietet StackExchange keine Funktion einer privaten Nachricht, daher muss ich diesen Kommentar nutzen: Wie ich gerade beim durchlesen einiger älterer Beiträge bemerkt habe, hat sich Marzipanherz offenbar nicht *gelöscht*, sondern *umbenannt* in **Arsak** - und war deshalb unter dem alten Namen natürlich nicht mehr auffindbar. Hoffe, mit dieser Mitteilung Dein Bedauern geschmälert zu haben.

Comment: @Volker: Danke. Schön, dass die Marzipanfraktion nicht geschrumpft ist. :)

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Ich vermute mal dass Du das mit cholerisch verwechselst.

Comment: Kann mir bitte jemand das Downvoting erklären - mal abgesehen davon dass meine Frage keine Antwort zu haben scheint.

Comment: @Kitana, Ihre Vermutung ist falsch. _melan_ (μέλαν): schwarz/dunkel; _cholia_ (χολία): Galle; also _Melancholie_: Schwarzgalligkeit

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich OK, falsche Vermutung meinerseits. Allerdings scheint, laut verschiedener Wörterbücher, der Begriff Melancholie vom Griechischen, über das Lateinische in's Deutsche gekommen zu sein. Bei meiner ersten Suche bin ich nur bis zum lateinischen Bezug gekommen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ich kenne da nur das lateinische

> dulcamarus

von [*dulcus* (süß)](https://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung/deutsch-latein/s%C3%BC%C3%9F) und [*amarus* (bitter)](https://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung/deutsch-latein/bitter)

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dulcamarus

Comment: Perfect & fast ;) (Und auch Bestandteil von https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bittersüßer_Nachtschatten)

Comment: Hmm... wie könnte man das eindeutschen? Dulzamarisch - klingt nicht wirklich brauchbar? Ich suche ein Synonym/Fremdwort welches den Schwerpunkt auf das Gefühl und nicht den Geschmack bittersüss legt.

Comment: So richtig viele Synonyme scheint es nicht zu geben.

Comment: Ich finde "dolzamarös" gut klingen. Aber ich habe keine Ahnung, ob es das schon gibt. Wenn nicht, sollte das jemand erfinden. <g> Übrigens, im Italienischen gibt es wohl [*dolceamaro*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/dolceamaro/).

Comment: Wie wär's mit einfach ***dulzamar*** (mit Betonung auf der letzten Silbe)? - *Oh, was für eine dulzamare Sinphonie!*

Comment: @Christian: Bitte, nicht singen! Und "Dulzamar" klingt irgendwie nach Cervantes und nicht so sehr nach Robbie Williams. Oder wie ein Ferienort an der andalusischen Küste.

Comment: 1. _bittersüß_ drückt einen ambivalenten Seelenzustand aus, in dem Trauer als lustvoll erlebt wird. 

2. _zartbitter_ (von Schokolade) ist kein Synonym zu _bittersüß_.

Answer (score 0):

> süßsauer

bezieht sich üblicherweise auf den Geschmack, aber eben nicht immer.

> Mit süßsaurer Miene musste Ursula Stenzel (...) das Wahlplakat (...) enthüllen.
>
> Rossi nahm alles mit einem süßsauren Lächeln zur Kenntnis.
>
> <sup>[Quelle](https://www.dwds.de/r?q=s%C3%BC%C3%9Fsauer&corpus=public&date-start=1473&date-end=2018&genre=Belletristik&genre=Wissenschaft&genre=Gebrauchsliteratur&genre=Zeitung&format=full&sort=date_desc&limit=50)</sup>

Es gibt übrigens auch »sauersüß«.

> Die SPD verfolgt den Streit mit sauersüßer Miene (...)
>
> (...) wenn Sie das sauersüße Gesicht gesehen hätten, das ich gemacht haben muss (...)
>
> <sup>[Quelle](https://www.dwds.de/r?q=sauers%C3%BC%C3%9F&corpus=public&date-start=1473&date-end=2018&genre=Belletristik&genre=Wissenschaft&genre=Gebrauchsliteratur&genre=Zeitung&format=full&sort=date_desc&limit=50)</sup>

Comment: Danke für Deine Antwort. Leider kann ich den Zusammenhang zu meiner Frage nicht erkennen. Kannst Du das näher erklären?

Comment: @Kitana: _»bittersüß«_, _»süßsauer«_ und _»sauersüß«_ enthalten jeweils zwei einander widersprechende Elemente, können im Kontext _»Gefühle«_ verwendet werden und sind bei metaphorischem Gebrauch inhaltlich nicht sonderlich weit voneinander entfernt.

Comment: Ich finde die Elemente nicht *widersprechend*, sondern *unterschiedlich*. Etwas kann etwas sauer und etwas süß sein. Und etwas Süßes kann einen bitteren Nachgeschmack haben (davon ist wohl auch die Bezeichnung für das Gefühl abgeleitet). Das widerspricht sich nicht und es gibt auch keinen Paradox.

Comment: Finde ich nicht unbedingt ein Synonym. Bittersüß (vor allem als Gefühl) bedeutet dass etwas süß (angenehm) ist, aber einen bitteren (traurigen) "Nachgeschmack" hat. Süßsauer ist wohl was ganz anderes und nicht unbedingt ein Gefühl.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Ich meine, dass die drei Konstruktionen jeweils das Zusammentreffen von etwas Behaglichem und etwas Unbehaglichem beschreiben, das ist die Gemeinsamkeit. Ob man das Unbehagliche nun bitter oder sauer nennt, ist meines Erachtens zweitrangig.

Comment: Was "behaglich" oder angenehm ist ist Ansichtsache. Ich persönlich mag saure Gurken, sauren Hering, Sauerbraten, aber auch Zartbitter-Schokolade, Tonic Water, Bitter Lemon oder Espresso. Ich mag allerdings keine sehr süßen Sachen wie Honig. Und ich mag gelegentlich Salzlakritz.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Mahlzeit!

Comment: @Pollitzer: nicht alles gleichzeitig. <g> Aber, "Danke!" (glaube ich sagen zu müssen, obwohl ich im Moment nur Kaffee trinke).

Comment: *bittersǘßes Lächeln* (Bsp. von DWDS, wo auch keine Synonyme stehen) oder *süßsaures Lächeln* wären wohl nicht gleichbedeutend, schon weil *sauer* und *bitter* im Übertragenen Sinne je eine feste Bedeutung haben.

Comment: @vectory: Wenn ich Geld finde und mir beim Bücken den Kopf anschlage, ist das dann süßsauer oder bittersüß? – Ich glaube, es geht beides.

Comment: Ich glaube das wäre sußsauer. Vielleicht glaube ich das nur der Abfolge wegen, erst süß, dann sauer. Ich denke insgesamt wäre diese situation weder noch, sondern einfach *ungeschickt*, *verdutzt*. Letztendlich weiß ich nicht, wie du in dem Moment fühlen und kucken würdest Und selbst wenn, ein einzelnes Beispiel ließe sich nur schwerlich verallgemeinern. Da die Worte so nah beisammen stehen, dürfte es eher instinktiver Reflex sein, eine Unterscheidung darin zu suchen, so wie in einzelnen Gefühlsregungen. Ich glaube, die Frage versucht den Begriff zu konkretisieren, nicht auszuweiten.

Comment: @Pollitzer: Bittersüß: süß mit bitterem Nachgeschmack.

Answer (score 0):

Eine Sinngemäße Übersetzung (nicht in Latein, sondern allenfalls innerhalb des Deutschen mit seinen lateinischen Fremdworten) zu finden dürfte schwer sein, da entweder die Poetische Note, oder der Sinn verlustig gehen.

> [pathetisch](https://www.dwds.de/wb/pathetisch)
>
> Adj. ‘voller Gefühl und Leidenschaft, ausdrucksvoll, feierlich, erhaben’, entlehnt (Anfang 17. Jh.) aus gleichbed. spätlat. pathēticus, griech. pathētikós (παθητικός), eigentlich ‘leidend, empfindend, äußerer Eindrücke fähig’, einer Ableitung von griech. páthos (s. unten). Heute oft im Sinne von ‘hochtrabend, salbungsvoll’. **Pathos** n. ‘leidenschaftlicher Gefühlsausdruck, feierliches Ergriffensein, feierlich-erhabene Darstellungs- oder Sprechweise, Gefühlserregung’ (Ende 17. Jh.), griech. páthos (πάθος) ‘(Miß)geschick, Leid, Gemütsbewegung, Leidenschaft’. Heute auch ‘übertriebener Gefühlsausbruch’.

Passt nicht perfekt, insofern das leidende Element üblicher Weise nicht mehr so gesehen wird, ebenso wie *Leidenschaft* inzwischen ausschließlich positiv gedeutet wird.

Das Lied von the Verge hat jedoch *Pathos* kann man so sagen, und dürfte für viele jüngere Menschen, mich zumindest, die markante Definition des Begriffs sein (soll heißen, ich muss bei dem Wort immer an das Lied denken). Das Lied zu beschreiben ist aber schwer, denn Wie Frank Zappa schon sagte. Über Musik reden ist wie über Architektur fischen. Da das Lied durch die Musik zum Film *Eiskalte Engel* bekannt wurde, kann man kurz *heiß-kalt* zum Vergleich heranziehen, das aber ebenso schwierig zu deuten ist.

Ich weiß ehrlich gesagt nicht, wie ich mir ein *Bittersüßes Lächeln* vorstellen soll. Die in der Frage genannte Deutung *melancholisch* trifft den Kern nicht, da Melancholia in Vier-Säfte-Lehre mit schwarzer Galle gleichgesetzt wird, die einfach nur bitter ist. Ansonsten wäre verwundernd, weshalb

> melancholisch

nicht als Antwort gelten sollte.

Comment: Pathetisch und melancholisch sind wohl beide was anderes. Pathetisch hat eine leicht negative Konnotation (der Übertreibung; also nicht mehr nur "mit viel Pathos", was noch positiv wäre), und melancholisch ist eher rückblickend und schwermütig.

Answer (score 0):

Etwas weniger poetisch wäre *traurig-schön* bzw. *tragisch-schön*, wobei bittersüß vielleicht noch die gesteigerte Form davon ist, da noch gegensätzlicher. Oder man nimmt *schmerzvoll* als Synonym für *bitter* und kombiniert das mit Synonymen für *süß*, wie z.B. *schmerzvoll zauberhaft*... <sup>([1](https://synonyme.woxikon.de/synonyme/bitter.php))([2](https://synonyme.woxikon.de/synonyme/s%C3%BC%C3%9F.php))</sup>